# EFCore looks for xxxId as ForeignKey instead of xxx

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core

I use EFCore.

In my Entity, there are this Properties:

```
    [Column("ReleasedFrom")]
    public string ReleasedFromPersNr { get; set; }
    public LoginUser ReleasedFrom { get; set; }
```

ReleasedFromPersNr is the ForeignKey-Property for the NavigationProperty ReleasedFrom. The column on the Database is ReleaseFrom (like defined in the Column-Attribute). But EFCore uses the Column ReleaseFromId which generates this Exception:

> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Invalid column name
> 'ReleasedFromId'.'

This is the generated SQL-Select:

```
SELECT [w].[ID], [w].[ReleasedFromId] FROM [WochenrapportStunden] AS [w]
  WHERE [w].[ID] = 255547
```

but it should be

```
SELECT [w].[ID], [w].[ReleasedFrom] FROM [WochenrapportStunden] AS [w]
  WHERE [w].[ID] = 255547
```

What need I to do, that EFCore uses ReleasedFrom instead ReleasedFromId?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `[ForeignKey]` attribute, rather than the `[Column]` attribute.